# randomly mask/set nan x% of data points in huge xarray.DataArray

Tags: python, numpy, dask, python-xarray

I have a huge (~ 2 billion data points) `xarray.DataArray`. I would like to randomly delete (either mask or replace by `np.nan`) a given percentage of the data, where the probability for every data point to be chosen for deletion/masking is the same across all coordinates. I can convert the array to a `numpy.array` but I would preferably keep it in the dask chunks for speed.

my data looks like this:

```
>> data
<xarray.DataArray 'stack-820860ba63bd07adc355885d96354267' (variable: 8, time: 228, latitude: 721, longitude: 1440)>
dask.array<stack, shape=(8, 228, 721, 1440), dtype=float64, chunksize=(1, 6, 721, 1440)>
Coordinates:
* latitude   (latitude) float32 90.0 89.75 89.5 89.25 89.0 88.75 88.5 ...
* variable   (variable) <U5 u'fal' u'swvl1' u'swvl3' u'e' u'swvl2' u'es' 
* longitude  (longitude) float32 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1.0 1.25 1.5 1.75 2.0 
* time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-02-01 2000-03-01 ...
```

I defined

```py
frac_missing = 0.2
k = int(frac_missing*data.size)
```

this is what I already tried:

- [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891180/select-cells-randomly-from-numpy-array-without-replacement) works with `np.ndindex` but the `np.ndindex` object is converted to a list which is very slow. I tried circumventing the conversion and simply iterate over the `np.ndindex` object as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658111/random-sample-from-a-very-long-iterable-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788380/python-choose-random-line-from-file-then-delete-that-line/32792504#32792504) but iterating over the whole iterator is slow for ~ 2 billion data points.
- `np.random.choice(data.stack(newdim=('latitude','variable','longitude','time')),k,replace=False)` returns the desired subset of data points, but does not set them to nan

The expected output would be the `xarray.DataArray` with the given percentage of datapoints either set to `np.nan` or masked, preferably in the same shape and the same dask chunks.

Comment: Does `data[np.random.rand(*data.shape) < frac_missing] = np.nan` work? I haven't used dask, but this is how you would do it in numpy.

Comment: @user545424 this is an elegant solution, however, it creates a `numpy.array` of the same size as `data`, which is too slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion by [user545424](https://stackoverflow.com/users/545424/user545424) is an excellent start. In order to not run into memory issues, you can put it in a small user-defined function and map it on the DataArray using the method `apply_ufunc`.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

testdata = xr.DataArray(np.empty((100,1000,1000)), dims=['x','y','z'])

def set_random_fraction_to_nan(data):
    data[np.random.rand(*data.shape) < .8]=np.nan
    return data

# Set 80% of data randomly to nan
testdata = xr.apply_ufunc(set_random_fraction_to_nan, testdata, input_core_dims=[['x','y','z']],output_core_dims=[['x','y','z']], dask='parallelized')
```

For some more explanation on wrapping custom functions to work with xarray, see [here.](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/computation.html#comput-wrapping-custom)

Comment: when `testdata` is used for several final data products that are only lazily evaluated at the end, their patterns of missingness do not agree although the command was only executed once. This is quite unexpected behavior, can be solved with a `np.random.seed(0)` in the definition of the function (see my edit).