# xr.DataArray.where sets valid points to nan when using several dask chunks

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I am trying to randomly delete a fraction of a xr.DataArray (as described and with the help of the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56257429/randomly-mask-set-nan-x-of-data-points-in-huge-xarray-dataarray?noredirect=1#comment99140954_56257429)) and subsequently access only the values from the original dataset `data` that were deleted.

This works fine as long as the data is not stored in dask arrays or in only one dask array. As soon as I define chunks smaller than the total size of the data, the original values are set to nan.

```py
data = xr.DataArray(np.arange(5*5*5.).reshape(5,5,5), dims=('time','latitude','longitude'))
data.to_netcdf('/path/to/file.nc')
#data = xr.open_dataarray('/path/to/file.nc', chunks={'time':5}) # creates expected output
data = xr.open_dataarray('/path/to/file.nc', chunks={'time':2}) # creates observed output 

def set_fraction_randomly_to_nan(data, frac_missing):
    np.random.seed(0)
    data[np.random.rand(*data.shape) < frac_missing] = np.nan
    return data

data_lost = xr.apply_ufunc(set_fraction_randomly_to_nan, data.copy(deep=True), output_core_dims=[['latitude','longitude']], dask='parallelized', input_core_dims=[['latitude','longitude']], output_dtypes=[data.dtype], kwargs={'frac_missing': 0.5})

print(data[0,-4:,-4:].values)
# >>
# [[ 6.  7.  8.  9.]
# [11. 12. 13. 14.]
# [16. 17. 18. 19.]
# [21. 22. 23. 24.]]

print(data.where(np.isnan(data_lost),0)[0,-4:,-4:].values)
```

expected output of the last line: keep all values where `np.isnan(data_lost)` is True and set rest to zero

```py
[[ 6.  0.  0.  9.]
[ 0.  0.  0. 14.]
[16.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0. 22.  0. 24.]]
```

observed output of the last line: set all values where `np.isnan(data_lost)` is True *to nan* and set rest to zero

```py
[[nan  0.  0. nan]
[ 0.  0.  0. nan]
[nan  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0. nan  0. nan]]
```

Any help in how to get the expected result while still being able to divide my (originally much larger) data into chunks is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a notion of "deep copying" a dask array. Dask assumes that everything you apply to a dask array is a pure function (though this isn't directly enforced), so if you map a mutating function over the blocks of a dask array you are relying on undefined behavior.

The fix is to do the copy *inside* the applied function, e.g.,

```py
def set_fraction_randomly_to_nan(data, frac_missing):
    np.random.seed(0)
    data = data.copy()
    data[np.random.rand(*data.shape) < frac_missing] = np.nan
    return data
```